# Create a new column based on condition

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I want to create a new column based on conditions.

The table look like this:

[Table with two authors from UK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuFCB.png)

I want to create new columns `author_uk` and `country_uk` with UK values

[Table with new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izqSW.png)

Comment: Please don't link to images - add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text

Comment: Use Expression Transformation. In case of any issues show us what have you tried and what errors you're facing.